# Wrong Vue app being serving the on port 8080

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli, asp-net-core-spa-services

I created a Vue app using Vue CLI (`vue create foo-app`) to test out the whole process and see how I got on with Vue (using VS Code if it makes any difference).

All good, let's go again but for the actul app I want to use.

The next time I created an app using the Vue JS Template for ASP Net Core Web API from with Visual Studio (2019 edition) (let's call it `bar-app`). It built correctly and seemingly no problems.

However when I F5 to run the app from within Visual Studio, instead of getting `bar-app` I instead get `foo-app`.

The browser launches on port 50800, which is correct and configured within VS.
I can see the Vue server running on 8080, and if I point the browser there, I also get the wrong app displayed.

On startup I have:

```
app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
    spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        spa.UseVueCli(npmScript: "serve");
    }
});
```

And `package.json` has `"serve": "vue-cli-service serve"`.

If I manually run the Vue app on its own i.e. open a cmd window at the correct folder and run `npm run serve` I can see the server starts but on a different port, 8085, which serves the app I want (`bar-app`).

I have tried changing the `package.json` command to pass in the port but this fails as when I F5, VS is automatically appending `--port 8080` to it (and so the effective command issues is `"serve": "vue-cli-service serve --port 8080 -port8085"`

So:

- Where have I configured the port to be 8085?
- Why is VS running the app on 8080?

Comment: There is one more option in UseVueCli i.e port, you can use it like below:
```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{                    
   spa.UseVueCli(npmScript: "serve", port:8085);
}
```